# Change background position and image fade

Tags: html, css, transition

i want to change the background position and in front of that a img at the same time.

I have a bad solution used a second div and centered it with padding. But when i mouse over the padding of the first div the picture dont change the picture.

```
#contentright {
height: 58px;
width: 256px;
overflow:hidden;}
```

I've made a fiddle exemplifying my scenario. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f3rBc/1/)

Any solution how i can fix that? Greetz

Comment: My referee for this was at http://www.hellohikimori.com/ look at the footer... right side :)

Comment: Sry the full code was not to display look inside the jsFiddle please :)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, but what is the question?

Comment: i want that the logo and the background change at the same time. the problem is that when i mouse over the padding only the background change and not the logo

Comment: @crixom11 looks normal to me.

Comment: Just found a solution! :) Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[check in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M927W/)

```
    .logo {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background:url(http://s1.directupload.net/images/140101/hy2cqqkj.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
      background-position: center center;
   }
```

in logo class